# How to use Activities in Odoo16

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

[image]

Please tell me what is the name of this component, what conditions does it display based on, what component is it in odoo
For example, I have a model for assigning tasks with 4 fields: task, user_id, deadline, status (new/seen)
So how can I make the above notification box display new/nearly expired tasks?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
self.message_post(body=_('Created New Task'), subtype='mail.mt_comment', author_id=self.create_uid.partner_id.id)
```

To create a notice, use the `message_post()` method. This can be used from inside the create method for newly created tasks, or from within the expiry checking function to get notifications about their expiration.

Comment: thanks, but what I mean is that I want to display it in the notification box, like currently in the "project" module, when installed, it will automatically add a notification to the Activities menu bar, and I want to know how. To be able to customize my module, I can also add it, like in my example, I have a new task module, and on the notification bar it will show how many new tasks/tasks are about to expire.